How to leave meeting and close embed UI with Zoom Meeting SDK in a SPA?
I’m currently using Zoom Meeting SDK in a VueJS application.
I’ve successfully connected to the meeting but there’s a problem:
If the user leaves the meeting route, being a SPA, there’s no browser reloading, so the embed element keeps showing in the application.
Is there a simple way to leave the meeting and also remove the SDK UI from the DOM?
If the user clicks on the “Leave meeting” button, it works fine, but there’s no way to programmatically leave the meeting and remove the SDK elements from the DOM.
I've already tried the ZoomMTG.leaveMeeting function, but it only disconnects the user after 2 minutes, while keeping the UI in the application.

You would use a combination of v-if for conditional rendering of your template code, and Zoom SDK's inMeetingServiceListener function to listen for the meeting disconnect event, at which point you can set the v-if to false and hide the UI element.
<div id='meetingSDKElement' v-if="isConnected">
  <!-- Zoom Meeting SDK Component View Rendered Here -->
</div>

although you didn't specify, I assume Vue 3 and Composition API:
const isConnected = ref(true)
ZoomMtg.inMeetingServiceListener('onMeetingStatus', function (status) {
  // {status: 1(connecting), 2(connected), 3(disconnected), 4(reconnecting)}
  if (status === 3) {
    isConnected.value = false
  }
});

